# how to have a more granular look at how php-fpm is consuming cpu resources (pg_stat_statements for php)

Tags: php, laravel, profiling, monitoring, newrelic

I'm looking at the htop of our application server and clearly the php application is gobbling up the CPU:

[image]

I've tried using services like newrelic but then adding such agents to the application server caused a spike itself (see [this post](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/latency-increase-when-monitoring-php/47705/5?u=abbood)).

What other options do I have to trace the parts in my application that is consuming so much memory?

note: my stack is Laravel/Psotgresql/Nginx. I've already done a lot of optimization on the database side (thanks to psql powerful profiling tools such as [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgstatstatements.html)) but can't find any such tools for php.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/) to debug PHP script execution and resources consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at [forp](http://anthonyterrien.com/forp/) C php extension ?

Never used it myself, but it seems it is worth a try